# nxScript: TestScript must return a Boolean error

Tags: azure, powershell, devops, azure-policy

When creating a custom Guest Configuration policy assignment using nxScript, I get the error:

` InvokeDscResource() failed. errorMessage:PowerShell DSC resource nxScript  failed to execute Test functionality with error message:The TestScript script block must return a Boolean.

PowerShell DSC resource nxScript  failed to execute Test functionality with error message:The TestScript script block must return a Boolean.
`

However, my TestScript block does return a Boolean as far as I can tell:

`            ##### Define audit bash scripts #####
$bashScript = "
#!/bin/bash
systemctl is-enabled cron
"
#####################################

```
        # Run bash script
        $result = & bash -c $bashScript
        Write-Output "Result: $result"

        # Check for null result
        if ($result -eq $null) {
            return $false
        } else {
            # Check if result contains the desired string
            $containsDesiredString = $result -Like "*$using:desiredString*"
            return $containsDesiredString
        }`
```

I have tried running this as is, and testing the PowerShell function in isolation to make sure it does return a Boolean. The displayed error message was not expected.

Comment: It depends [When the input of an operator is a scalar value, the operator returns a Boolean value. When the input is a collection, the operator returns the elements of the collection that match the right-hand value of the expression.](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators#common-features). If you want to make sure it is a boolean, you should typecast it: `[bool]$containsDesiredString`

Comment: Thanks, I have taken your advice though I do not believe that was the issue. I suspect the 'Write-Output' was possibly being interpreted as something non-boolean being returned. I have removed that line and re-ran, currently waiting for the assignment status to show...